# Play Live Video Stream On Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I'am trying to make a website that only has a video player in it.

I currently have a softrware that streams video in HLS through a url, if i open the url in iphone with some HLS Player i can see the video.

What I'am trying to do is to publish the stream in all browsers(or some of them) with some video player

I'v tried jwplayer, but it doesnt stream my site, i tried jplayer but it doesnt do live streamin.

I basicly need a plyer that i can give it the url for example: http://someurl.com/Streaming/Live

and it will play the video.

Any help would be good.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't play HLS in website..

You must need format like RTMP or RTSP to play in website...

Try [Wowza](http://www.wowza.com/) they provide the all formats for websites, mobiles etc.

Comment: not in a website directly but through a video player that is embeded in the website i can.